# PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL: role "***" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I have a local version of my app working well, but I'm trying to push the data to my live app.  I'm running `rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production` and I get the `PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  role "***" does not exist` message.

I'm taking 'username' 'database' and 'password' in my .yml file as the details given under the Database Credentials for my heroku postgres addon

My .yml file:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: postgresql-rectangular-42683
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: postgresql-rectangular-42683
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
 adapter: postgresql
 encoding: utf8
 database: ***
 pool: 5
 username: ***
 password: *********
 #host: ***.***.***.*** #-> only for third party db server
```

Comment: You gotta create the role first or just use the existing role `username: postgres`

Comment: If you are using different username than `postgres`

Comment: If I use username: postgres and just the given database name of 'postgresql-rectangular-42683' then terminal throws no feedback and checking in heroku, there's been no update to the db.  How am I sure this is updating my prod db? especially as I'm running ENV=production?

Comment: Heroku doesn't use your database.yml

Comment: @DeepakMahakale are you entirely sure about that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FATAL: role "root" does not exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27984866/fatal-role-root-does-not-exist)

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#build-behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku services are dynamic and are subject to being moved amongst their entire fleet of hosts. As such, you should avoid hard coding those database credentials and configuration options. Instead, connect via the `DATABASE_URL` configuration variable which will be kept up-to-date on your behalf. Documentation for that [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-database-connection-behavior).

When you've made those changes and ensured that the migration has been pushed to your `heroku` remote you can complete the migration by running `heroku run rake db:migrate -a <app name>`

Comment: This was exactly what I ended up doing.